# Java: Ternary operator, not working as should

Tags: java, android

I have some sample code and it looks like it uses a ternery operator but it takes 3 items. So I am really confused, the ones I have seen in other languages take only 2, i.e. true and false.

Here is the code

```
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

what i wish to do is remove the line

```
     : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

So it would now be

```
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
```

but it states it is missing a : (colon) in the IDE. So maybe this isn't a ternery operator after all ?

THe ide I am using is Android Studio.

I know it must be something simple, but i can't figure it out.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Original code has 2x`?` and 2x`:` which is correct. Your changed code has 2x`?` and 1x`:` which is a syntax error. What do you actually want it to do?

Comment: @Marlin : If possible then use `:null` in place of `: analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);` if `null` check is handled in application

Comment: What type is `trackerId`?

Comment: If you only want the two `analytics.newTracker()` possibilities shown in your last code block, remove `(trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ?`.

Comment: The general idea of the ternery operator is this --> `result = testCondition ? value1 : value2`. Depending on the condition you assign 'something' to a variable. But you have max. 2 choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is nested ternary operators. Think of them as the following (pseudo-code below)

```
  condition ? answerifTrue : secondternaryoperator;
  where secondternaryoperator =
        secondcondition ? answerifTrue : answerIfFalse;
```

Basically, this is two ternary operators combined. If the first condition is true it simply returns `answerifTrue`. But if the condition is false, it runs the second ternary operator to determine what to return based on a second condition. A singular ternary operator simply looks like this;

```
  condition ? answerifTrue : answerIfFalse;
```

So if you want to create a single ternary operator from both you need to determine which answer you want if the first condition is false, for example;

```
  Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker) : analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
```

I imagine however, that what you need isn't well suited to ternary operators anyway and you might need to restructure the statement entirely into `if else` blocks or a switch statement.

Comment: Wow I missed that, yes, nested operators.. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, as far as I understand that use case you have to do something like this:

```
 Tracker t = null; 

 if (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
 } else if (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
 } else {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
 }
```